# How to make Squid Proxy undetectable by ip-check.net?

Tags: http, proxy, server, configuration, squid

I have setup squid proxy on a CentOs server where I set `forwarded_for` to delete and denied request headers on the `/etc/squid/squid.conf` file. However, whilst connected to the proxy, if I visit http://ip-check.net/detect-proxy.php it still detects that I'm using a proxy. How can I configure Squid to hide the fact that I'm using a proxy?

Comment: The relevant detail here is how that service detects proxies. Do you know that detail?

Comment: For Reviewers: In my opinion it is normal question. It fits Security SE and arguably also Superuser SE. I keep it open.

Comment: Not sure if squid will add extra headers and that service is checking that...

Comment: Here's the [sanitized] config I use on every new Squid install: https://antipaucity.com/2018/07/18/a-fairly-comprehensive-squid-configuration-for-proxying-all-the-http-things/#.YDe5S2NOmc4. I've never had a proxy identified by any of these 5 sites using that config: https://antipaucity.com/2018/10/11/do-you-leak/#.YDe5pmNOmc4.

Answer (score 2):

The URL you've used seems to determine if a client uses a proxy not (only) based on HTTP headers but also where the request comes from.

To check I've used `ssh -Dport dst`, which creates a SOCKS proxy listening locally on the given port and where the traffic then comes out of the proxy with the IP address of the SOCKS endpoint. I've tried this with an external system at some public hoster and with localhost as a target: in case of localhost the URL claimed that no proxy was used while in case of the external system it claimed that a proxy was used. But the difference here was only in the source IP of the traffic, not in the use of a proxy.

While no details are known it is possible that this specific detection algorithm distinguishes between IP addresses which are associated with public hosting sites and other IP addresses, and in the first case simply assumes the use of some proxy, VPN or similar.